# MacOS Preview text extraction from image not working properly in Japanese

Tags: macos, preview, japanese

I'm on a MacBook Pro 2021 with M1, running on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1

I tried to use text extraction feature of Preview, since I can't select text in Spotify and I wanted to search the song I'm listening.

I selected the text by toggling Tools > Text Selection then pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

[image: screenshot on macOS of Preview app with text extraction not selecting every Japanese text]

As can be seen in image, it does not select every text in image.

How can extract all the text from an image in Japanese on Preview?

Comment: It’s actually not clear at all.  Are you trying to select text from a screen shot?  What file format?  PNG?

Comment: I have found translating from images to be somewhat flakey as you describe.  You may want to let Apple know via http://www.apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 0):

### <sup>*Feel free to edit this answer to update it according to the flow of new updates and releases.*</sup>

If you're running a macOS version below macOS Ventura (13), Japanese will not be available for you to use with Live Text (that's how the feature is called). Here is the list of languages supported for Live Text on macOS Ventura (tested by me - *feel free to edit this answer to add more supported languages if you find some more*) :

- English
- French
- Spanish
- Portuguese
- Japanese
- Chinese
- Ukrainian
- Italian

Apparently, Japanese, Korean, and Ukrainian got added with macOS Ventura (and iOS 16). If you are running a macOS version prior to Ventura, you will not be able to select Japanese text in pictures.

---

#### If you are running macOS Ventura - Alternatives

I do not know why it is not working on Preview but I can propose you an alternative that should work.

You can use the **Photos** app for this. Normally, your screenshot will be saved in the Photos app on your Mac.

To be able to copy the text from it, open Photos, choose the screenshot you have taken. Then, hover the text you want to copy with your cursor and drag over the text to select it. You can then copy your selection by pressing <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+Click on it and selecting "Copy text" or pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. You can also choose to translate it but doing <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+Click and selecting "Translate text".

For more options and informations, see [Interact with text in a photo using Live Text in Photos on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/guide/photos/pht6bc6bd5f5/mac).

Note : Live Text also works in Quick Look and Safari.

Comment: Hi, sorry for skipping version info on original post, I'm running on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: @DerinAşır Okay, I have made an "Alternatives" section for this case. :)

Answer (score 0):

If translation is your purpose, you can also upload images to google translate.  Below is the result for the one you posted.

[image]